# How to iterate a set of code in jsp.?

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I want to iterate this set of code using jsp, (I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1)

```
<div class ="grid">
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="Selected_Game.jsp?gameid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
                <img src="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">
                <div class="GName"> 
                    <%=rs.getString(3)%></div>
                <div class="Cost">Rs.<%=rs.getInt(5)%></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe , you are retrieving data from database.
Then, write your code like this

```
<div class ="grid">
<% 
while (rs.next()) {  // check for next row and display data accordingly
%>
  <div class="img">
        <a target="_blank" href="Selected_Game.jsp?gameid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
            <img src="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="GName"> 
                <%=rs.getString(3)%></div>
            <div class="Cost">Rs.<%=rs.getInt(5)%></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<% 
 }   //end of while loop
%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to put that code in a loop, or reuse it like an include.

Iterate (looping)

You can wrap that code in a for loop:

```
<% for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) { %>
  html and jsp code in here
  <%= i %>
<% } %>
```

Iterate (repeating)

You can put that code in a snippet/tag and include it:

```
<jsp:include page="hello.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSTL's [**C:for-each tag**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/JSTLForEachLoopwithBeginEndStep.htm)

```
 <c:forEach var="person" items="${people.people}" varStatus="rowCounter">

      </c:forEach>
```